# How do I run a script on VxWorks Tornado Shell?

Tags: vxworks

I am trying to run a script on VxWorks Shell, which will load a module.

I use a Perl script to telnet into the system, login and get access to the shell.

I am able to run the basic commands like `'i'`, `'time'`, `'ls'` `'pwd'` and `'h'` and so on.

But I would like to run a script, say 'test.o'.

If I do : `<C:\Path\subfolder\test.o`  the script file WILL run from, the TORNADO Shell.

But I have connected to using Telnet using Perl.

So I connect this way:

```
use Net::Telnet;
my $username = "username"; 
my $password = "password";

my $t = new Net::Telnet(Timeout=>10, Errmode=>'die');
$t->open('10.42.177.123');
$t->login($username,$password);                    # Logins as expected.
my @lines = $t->cmd('i');                          # To test
print @lines                                       # This works
@lines = $t->cmd('<C:\\Path\\Subfolder\\test.o');  # This is not working for me. HELP!
print @lines;                                      # Prints the Error below
```

I get an error saying :

```
Unknown directory: /C:\Path\Subfolder
can't open input 'C:\Path\Subfolder\test.o
  errno = 0x1f5
-
```

How do I run my script file if it is residing at a particular folder of the host PC?

I am able to run the script manually from the TORNADO SHELL window where the prompt looks like  `->`. and hence it is a working script. And as I have said, I am able to run and print the basic VxWorks Shell commands ("build-in functions").

Any help? [ My OS is Win7 ]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is issue is now resolved. Two issues was there, and one was because TORNADO, another VxWorks Client was also logged into the system at the same time, while I am trying run my perl script which sends commands and do instructions using Telnet, and having two clients (Tornado, and my scripts Telnet session) running at the same time (despite the VxWorks OS running on the Embedded system having TelnetDeamon running) it didn't like it.

As for the Error above, why it didn't work and gave an error was a syntax error. I should have used

```
$t->cmd('<\\Path\\subfolder\\test.o');
```

No need to give `C:`